# Cisco Jabber integration with MS azure bot service

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I created a chatbot using MS Azure Bot Service framework. 
I am using Bot Builder v3.12.2.4 and I do have a direct channel to my chatbot.

I would like to integrate this existing bot into jabber.

Has anyone already implemented such a solution? Using Directline API 3.0, XMPP, ...

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. But this question is too broad and lacks any research notes or supporting documentation. Please take some time to improve it. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A cursory Google search indicates that the answer to this question is no. It's possible to connect BotBuilder bots to other channels via custom 3rd party connectors, e.g. [botbuilder-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-line), but I have not seen anything for Jabber for Node or C#.